# VueJS multiple components in one view

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to learn VueJS and it's going well but i run into one problem where i can't get multiple components to work on one page, for some reason the html will load but everything in my  `export default` wont work.

So i have 2 components: a ShortenerComponent and a StatsComponent the ShortenerComponent works and does everything it should, but the StatsComponent will only load the html and will not do anything inside the `export default` this is my code:

StatsComponent.vue (the ShortenerComponent is the same except for the methods and html.):

```
<script>
// get the csrf token from the meta
var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

export default {
    data() {
        return {

        };
    },

    test() {
        this.getStats();
    },
    methods: {
        // get all the existing urls
        getStats() {
            console.log('console log something');
            axios.get('urls').then((response) => {
                console.log('console log something');
            });
        },

    }
}
```

My shortenercomponent:

```
<script>
// get the csrf token from the meta
var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            shortUrl: '',
            url: '',
            error: '',
        };
    },

    methods: {
        createUrl() {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/',
                data: {
                    _token: csrf_token,
                    url: this.url
                },
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.shortUrl = response.data.hash;
            }).catch(error => {
                this.error = error.response.data.message;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and last but not least my app.js file

```
Vue.component('shortener',require('./components/ShortenerComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('stats', require('./components/StatsComponent.vue'));

var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

I hope someone could figure out what i did wrong :D

Comment: can you show what error is shown in console ?

Comment: No error shown in console

Comment: Are you using webpack ? Also make sure vue-loader is set correctly in webpack.

Comment: Where is the template showing the components being used ?

Comment: Well, the problem is in the StatsComponent.vue because only that does not work correctly. @mathk it is showing in a welcome.blade.php.

Comment: There is no data,  no mounted, no created attribute in your component. What are you expecting to show?

Comment: What is `test`? Is that supposed to be in `methods`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my code i had the `test` method, i thought that would call the `getStats` method. What i did not now is that Vue has the created method used to run code after an instance is created.

So what i had to do was:

```
function created()
{
   this.getStats();
}
```

Source: [Vue instance Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

Comment: Considering the author himself is the one who made the comment, it kind of does provide a LQ answer to the question